# Confusion on Hartogs' extension theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am working on an example of [Hartogs' extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_extension_theorem#Formal_statement_and_proof).

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a set $G \setminus K$, where $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, ($n ≥ 2$) and $K$ is a compact subset of $G$. If the complement $G \setminus K$ is connected, then $f$ can be extended to a unique holomorphic function $F$ on $G$.

If we consider the 2D case $f(z,w)= \frac{ 1 }{ z^2 + w^2 + 1 }$, then $f$ is holomorphic in the domain $\{ (z,w) \mid |z|^2 + |w|^2 < 1 \}$. Now if we let $G = \{ (z,w) \mid |z|^2 + |w|^2 < 2 \} $, which is open, and let $K = \{ (z,w) \mid 1 \le |z|^2 + |w|^2 < 2 \}$, which is a compact subset of $G$, then $G\setminus K$ is connected and $f$ is holomorphic on $G\setminus K$.
So Hartogs' extension theorem implies that $f$ extends to a holomorphic function $F$ on $G$. I am unable to see what the extension would be. For example, what would be $F(i,0)$, where $f(i,0) = \infty$?

Comment: why is $K$ compact?

Comment: @Conrad Sorry. Isn't $G - K$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is connected?

Comment: @Conrad Thank you so much! I see it is not compact now.

Comment: Happy to be of help